# Display tracked changes in Jubula

Tags: automated-testing, java, eclipse, jubula

I'm using [Jubula](http://eclipse.org/jubula/) 8.0 (Eclipse Feature 2.3) and I've turned on the 'Track changes' check-box for a project.

Where can I see the changes that anyone made?
Is there a CVS/SVN-styled View in Eclipse to track those or it's only traceable from a table in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the changes made in the properties view for e.g. Test Case Editors. There is an entry in there for "changes" when the change tracking is active.